# Is there any use to duplicate column names in a table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In sqlite3, I can force two columns to alias to the same name, as in the following query:

```
SELECT field_one AS overloaded_name,
       field_two AS overloaded_name
FROM my_table;
```

It returns the following:

```
overloaded_name  overloaded_name
---------------  ---------------
1                2
3                4
...              ...
```

... and so on.

However, if I create a named table using the same syntax, it appends one of the aliases with a `:1`:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE temp AS
          SELECT field_one AS overloaded_name,
                 field_two AS overloaded_name
          FROM my_table;
sqlite> .schema temp
CREATE TABLE temp(
  overloaded_name TEXT,
  "overloaded_name:1" TEXT
);
```

I ran the original query just to see if this was possible, and I was surprised that it was allowed.  Is there any good reason to do this?  Assuming there isn't, why is this allowed at all?

**EDIT**:

I should clarify: the question is twofold:  why is the table creation allowed to succeed, and (more importantly) why is the original select allowed in the first place?

Also, see my clarification above with respect to table creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can force two columns to alias to the same name...
>   why is [this] allowed in the first place?

This can be attributed to the [shackles of compatibility](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Importance-of-Column-Names.pdf). In the SQL Standards, nothing is ever deprecated. An early version of the Standard allowed the result of a table expression to include columns with duplicate names, probably because an influential vendor had allowed it, possibly due to the inclusion of a bug or the omission of a design feature, and weren't prepared to take the risk of breaking their customers' code (the shackles of compatibility again).

> Is there any use to duplicate column names in a table?

[In the relational model, every attribute of every relation has a name that is unique within the relevant relation](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WuZGD5tBfMwC&pg=PA62&dq=Column+Naming+in+SQL&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pnoNT-75FMKxhAeC2PG7BA&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Column%20Naming%20in%20SQL&f=false). Just because SQL allows duplicate column names that doesn't mean that as a SQL coder you should utilise such as feature; in fact I'd say you have to vigilant not to invoke this feature in error. I can't think of any good reason to have duplicate column names in a table but I can think of many obvious bad ones. Such a table would not be a relation and that can't be a good thing!

> why is the [base] table creation allowed to succeed

Undoubtedly an 'extension' to (a.k.a purposeful violation of) the SQL Standards, I suppose it could be perceived as a reasonable feature: if I attempt to create columns with duplicate names the system automatically disambigutes them by suffixing an ordinal number. In fact, the SQL Standard specifies that there be an implementation dependent way to ensure the result of a table expression does not *implicitly* have duplicate column names (but as you point out in the question this does not perclude the user from *explicitly* using duplicate `AS` clauses). However, I personally think the Standard behaviour of disallowing the duplicate name and raising an error is the correct one. Aside from the above reasons (i.e. that duplicate columns in the same table are of no good use), a SQL script that creates an object without knowing if the system has honoured that name will be error prone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  The linked source (presentation?) was interesting, but was only tangentially related.  If you could be so kind as to provide further references, I feel like your answer could more completely address my question.

Comment: @Nate: I have added a link (source) for the second part of my answer. For the first part of my answer, I have no further link: the only freely-available SQL Standard spec is for [SQL-92 (draft)](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt). The third part of my answer is wholly my opinion :)

Answer (score 2):

The table itself can't have duplicate column names because inserting and updating would be messed up.  Which column gets the data?

During selects the "duplicates" are just column labels so do not hurt anything.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about the `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT` command. This looks like an SQL extension to me.

Standard SQL does not allow you to use the same column name for different columns, and SQLite appears to be allowing that in its extension, but working around it. While a simple, naked `select` statement simply uses `as` to set the column name, `create table ... as select` uses it to create a brand new table with those column names.

> As an aside, it would be interesting to see what the naked `select` does when you try to *use* the duplicated column, such as in an `order by` clause.

If you were allowed to have multiple columns with the same name, it would be a little difficult for the execution engine to figure out what you meant with:

```
select overloaded_name from table;
```

The reason why you can do it in the select is to allow things like:

```
select id, surname   as name from users where surname is not null
union all
select id, firstname as name from users where surname is     null
```

so that you end up with a *single* `name` column.

As to whether there's a good reason, SQLite is *probably* assuming you know what you're doing when you specify the same column name for two different columns. Its essence seems to be to allow a great deal of latitude to the user (as evidenced by the fact that the columns are dynamically typed, for example).

The alternative would be to simply refuse your request, which is what *I'd* prefer, but the developers of SQLite are probably more liberal (or less anal-retentive) than I :-)

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I appreciate your union example, that was helpful.  If you could provide a couple references, I think this could successfully answer the question.